# How to connect one database with multiple window applications?

Tags: database, wpf, one-to-many, saas, software-distribution

I have installed one window application(software) in multiple computers but is it possible to stored same database of that application in only one machine/computer? like, window application (software) is installed or used in multiple PCs but the database is stored and used from only one machine.

Answer (score 0):

I do this often. As long as the workstation housing the database is visible to the other machines (and it is configured to accept remote connections (generally over port 1433)), the same connection string should work for all of them to access that data (you need the REAL machine name... not a "."). Always accessing fresh data, establishing how conflicts are handled, and other issues would likely be more problematic than setting up the same program on several machines and accessing on common database (... and then again, maybe your program only reads data, in which you wouldn't have any of those problems.

Comment: Thank you for reply but can you explain or give a demo of a connection string path so i can understand more easily.

Comment: I may show you the wrong type of string, so instead head over to https://www.connectionstrings.com/ and it will construct the right one for you (or do the easy thing and add an *edmx model to your project (right click project\add\ADO.NET Entity Model).